# Is there a way to check if class member access on instantiation?

Tags: php

So in PHP 5.4 and up you can call a method on instantiation like so.

```
$class = new Foo()->methodName();
```

I would like to check when the class is instantiated if it was done so with a method at the same time.

Is it possible to check if the class was instantiated without a method at the same time and default to a method if not?

Comment: Can you really chain as above? https://3v4l.org/jaOV9

Comment: I can however do this: `($head = new Head())->donHat();`  Notice instantiation happens first, then the method is called here.  There is no easy way to determine the future method call at instantiation.

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Reflection might be able to do it but without more info I can't be more specific.  By the way, PHP 5.4 has not been supported for a long time and if you're running a publicly facing application you're in real danger of falling victim to a security exploit.

Comment: I am running PHP 7. I just mentioned 5.4 because that is when the feature became available.

Answer (score 0):

you can use instanceOf on the object for which you wanted to check the class.

Answer (score -1):

Constructor of the class cannot return a value in php, so you can't use singleton incapsulated in constructor and have it looks nice. Of cource, you can make something like this

```
// NOT FOR USE
class Foo {
    private static $instance;
    public function __construct($skipIncapsulate = false) {
        if (!$skipIncapsulation && !self::$instance)
        {
             self::instance = new self(true);
        }
    }

    public function bar() {
        // Do what you want with self::$instance
    }
}
```

> N.B. Do not use the example above, it is ugly solution, which also incapsulates unnecessary logic in controller, and while working with the class

Better use a usual singleton like this

```
class Foo {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {}

    public static getInstance()
    {
        return self::$instance ?? self::$instance = new self();
    }
}
```

Nevertheless you can create a `new class FooManager`, which will delegate the if the `Foo` class is defined

```
class FooManager {
    private static $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$foo = self::$foo ?? self::$foo = new Foo();
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return self::$foo;
    }
}

// usage in your code
(new FooManager)->getFoo()->bar();
// You can add __call method to use (new FooManager)->foo->bar()
```

This will simplify working with your code. Incapsulating static self-instance in constructor is not the good practice

Comment: Sorry, but I can't condone a recommendation to use a singleton when there are vastly superior approaches like dependency injection

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do, of course you can youse di or IOC, but according the explanation of your question it is not about di and IOC etc